# jquery check if radio button is checked and then check if tickbox is checked

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox, radio-button

Hi, I have a two part form which I have developed. One is for existing members and one is not.

On one of the forms I have a checkbox which will need to be checked before they can proceed, to determine that they are on the correct form. I will use the radio button which hides and unhides forms.

However when I try to get a handle on if the radio button is checked and then checking to see if the checkbox is checked I get nothing returned.

Can someone help me implement this? My JS is below or view my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pECzh/4/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var check;   

    if($("input:radio[name=existingpartner]").is(":checked")){

        // Example 3 - With jQuery prop  
    $("#test-with-prop").on("click", function(){
        check = $("#mycheckbox").prop("checked");
        if(check) {
             alert("Checkbox is checked.");
        } else {
            alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Your radio buttons have two ids each. They should also share the same name.

Comment: @j08691 updated http://jsfiddle.net/pECzh/5/ but still doesn't make a difference

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to be an answer; I was just pointing our some fundamental flaws. Also, your revised code still doesn't share the same name for your radio buttons.

Comment: Change the name property not the id of input for radio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if statement you are checking if the element is checked, but in the DOM the element is not checked therefore it will not bind the event on the button.

Move the if statement inside the bind event.

```
$("#test-with-prop").on("click", function () {
    if ($("input:radio[name=existingpartner]").is(":checked")) {
        check = $("#mycheckbox").prop("checked");
        if (check) {
            alert("Checkbox is checked.");
        } else {
            alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/pECzh/8/)